# xampp 1.8.1 doesn't show websites with .htaccess in folder

Tags: apache, .htaccess, xampp, localhost

I used **xampp 1.7.7** with *"Apache/2.2.11 (Win32) DAV/2 mod_ssl/2.2.11 OpenSSL/0.9.8i PHP/5.2.9 Server at localhost Port 80"*, and everything works just fine. I wanted to migrate from xampp 1.7.7 to **xampp 1.8.1** with *"Apache/2.4.2 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1c PHP/5.4.4 Server at localhost Port 80"*, i use **.htaccess** file with **mod_rewrite.so** module and everything worked fine with xampp 1.7.7 but when I switched to 1.8.1 in the directory structure of `http://localhost` **I don't see folder with .htaccess file inside them, when i try to access those folders trough direct link like `http://localhost/example` it trows Error 500**.

`LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so` is unquoted.

My operating system is Windows 7.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: _LoadModule expires_module modules/mod_expires.so_ was commented and I have **ExpiresActive On** in .htaccess, for everyone else who has that problem:-)

Comment: I have the same problem, it can't be solved by your suggestion, please help me if you have anything other than this. Thank You.